# IOS Chart 4 addDataSet(dataSet) no longer working after upgrading

Tags: charts, swiftui

I decided to upgrade to danielgindi Charts 4.0 using SwiftUI.

Now all my data.addDataSet(dataSet) are giving me "Value of type 'BarChartData' has no member 'addDataSet'" errors.

Here is some sample code.

Note that my data is coming from an API so it has to be updated after the information has downloaded.

What changed between 3 & 4?

Thanks.

```
    import Charts
    import SwiftUI 
      
    struct ValueBarChart : UIViewRepresentable {
      
         var entries : [BarChartDataEntry]
     
        func makeUIView(context: Context) -> BarChartView {
           
            let chart = BarChartView()
           
            chart.data = addData()
            
            return chart
            
        }
         
        func updateUIView(_ uiView: BarChartView, context: Context) {
            uiView.data = addData()
        }
        
        func addData( ) -> BarChartData {
            
            let data = BarChartData()
            
            let dataSet = BarChartDataSet(entries: entries)

             
            data.addDataSet(dataSet)  // Value of type 'BarChartData' has no member 'addDataSet'
              
            return data
            
        }
        
        typealias UIViewType = BarChartView
        
    }
```

Answer (score 12):

It appears that it has changed to .append() in version 4.0.